# Indexing error on same type of string with same index length after using split method

Tags: python, csv, dataset, data-science

I have 2 CSV files, working with VS Code. And I am trying to extract the 2nd index values to a new column.

For 1st CSV file

```
csv1['Location'] = Albuquerque, NM

df['Location'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0]) produces Albuquerque
df['Location'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1]) produces NM
```

For 2nd CSV file

```
csv2['Location'] = Bromley, England
df['Location'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0]) produces Bromley
df['Location'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1]) produces an out of range error.
```

Both produce <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> when using type() method.

Does anyone know why this is happening? as much as I know both strings are of the same index format that is why [0] produces the 1st index values for both CSV files and [1] should work for both files.

Comment: It is because some of your strings have a single value, for example, imagine `'hello'.split(',')[1]` - this will raise you an error because there is only one index in the list and you are trying to reach index `1`. Check your strings first. If you need the last value, you can change `[1]` to `[-1]`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have reformated my question for more coherence. Can you please have a look at it again?

Comment: I am not sure what is inside of `csv2` but its clear that the error is what I described, that some of your strings are of `len` `1`, you should add some data.